# Html.Partial string combine for view file name

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razorengine

Why is this not working:

```
@Html.Partial("Training" + Model.Week + Model.Page, Model);
```

My partial view file names: Training11.cshtml, Training12.cshtml, etc
And is there a solution for this? Otherwise I need to create 8 * 8 if(/switch) statements..

Comment: I don't know that it will add in the call.  try concatenating the fields into a variable and using that variable in the line

Comment: What do you mean by 'this not working'. What is the error?

Comment: Oops I made another mistake, it's just working!